# Cant spend input with non-standart redeemscript (OP_CSV)

Tags: bitcoind, script, input-script

I'm playing with OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY.

Here is my transaction that I'm trying to spend:

> https://tchain.btc.com/e79d469698915aa6724288ae3a4141a31706d081f39fb7fd0b956a73a9044b22

which has the folowing redeem script:

```
2 OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY f45d94733d430261962932e0c847075195916a04 OP_CHECKSIG
```

But got an error when I  broadcast it (after two block confirmations left):

```
mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Non-canonical DER signature) (code 16)
```

I have no issues to spend transaction if I:

1. Just specify `2 CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY` (can spend anyone)
2. With standart transaction `HASH160 f45d94733d430261962932e0c847075195916a04 OP_EQUAL`

but none with combination of them.
Here is a signed transaction:

```
0200000001224b04a9736a950bfdb79ff381d00617a341413aae884272a65a919896469de7000000006b4830450221008801d7f0e402724b090133ec01a817e993675a44a871f1a3afc0dba730e24ea4022044097be610bece524e90a743fa9d060cd194079105e6f6d150265a1164e722c3012103e8546cfe53ca9014f6a352bc2e5c1f7cec1f5b344c73d4db3ed3b8f075d5c9ef020000000120a107000000000017a914f45d94733d430261962932e0c847075195916a048700000000
```

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. With the folowing redeem script (OP_DROP added)

> https://tchain.btc.com/022d42355ac90e63f2667208112cf22471397dd2812645b5571da2d212596932

```
2 OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY OP_DROP f45d94733d430261962932e0c847075195916a04 OP_CHECKSIG
```

I got another error

```
(Script evaluated without error but finished with a false/empty top stack element) (code 16)
```

[UPDATED]:

> https://tchain.btc.com/46894d9dd5e20147826523b1a3ac8e8c5c64603338430d04bd6f5846af2bb9b4

```
3 OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY OP_DROP OP_HASH160 f45d94733d430261962932e0c847075195916a04 OP_EQUAL
```

Then trying to broadcast this tx:

```
0200000001b4b92baf46586fbd040d43383360645c8c8eaca3b12365824701e2d59d4d8946000000006a47304402205649f715d2553cc4a66dd36a61b3c1b187d19f585bd40427d795c600373a45ab02203325ef44a3aae191ed3f2a90efe382d7992712c03f249f8dd61d8a30997806dc012103e8546cfe53ca9014f6a352bc2e5c1f7cec1f5b344c73d4db3ed3b8f075d5c9ef0300000001e00f97000000000017a914f45d94733d430261962932e0c847075195916a048700000000
```

I got

```
error code: -26
error message:
mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Script evaluated without error but finished with a false/empty top stack element) (code 16)
```

Here is a privatekey

```
cUB1iazKDHngknjpTHUfKtH9zNRvHn1aBMPJbK2s913zUegjkeNn
```

Can someone spend it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must provide a `scriptSig` that, when executed with `scriptPubKey` results in a true (or any nonzero item) on the stack (and passes all verification ops).

The `scriptPubKey` you need to satisfy (with a `scriptSig`) is:

```
2 OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY f45d94733d430261962932e0c847075195916a04 OP_CHECKSIG
```

(note this is not the `redeemScript`)

There main problem is:

[`OP_CHECKSIG`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG) is looking for a public key, but you have provided a script hash: `f45d94733d430261962932e0c847075195916a04`. This will never be satisfied so this transaction output is not spendable.

If you want to use the same `redeemScript` as before, you probably want the following `scriptPubKey`:

`2 OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY OP_DROP HASH160 f45d94733d430261962932e0c847075195916a04 OP_EQUAL`

Note the `OP_DROP` because the `OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY` leaves the 2 on the stack.

In order to spend this, you must provide any signatures and the `redeemScript` whose hash equals `f45d94733d430261962932e0c847075195916a04`.

**Update**:

The `redeemScript` is still wrong. Instead of `03e8546cfe53ca9014f6a352bc2e5c1f7cec1f5b344c73d4db3ed3b8f075d5c9ef`, try `0014e17bbad678e82f8188099a351170c3e0efd4011b`. This is the `P2WPKH` script you used previously in https://tchain.btc.com/46894d9dd5e20147826523b1a3ac8e8c5c64603338430d04bd6f5846af2bb9b4. Also note this is a segwit script so it will look for the signature and pubkey in the witness data: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#p2wpkh

Comment: Shouldn't that be `OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <hash> OP_EQUAL OP_CHECKSIG`? Your example only verifies that the pubkey matches, it does not verify the signature.

Comment: I was attempting to provide a `P2SH` example, not a `P2PKH`.

Comment: Ah, of course, my mistake then!

Comment: Please, see my updated post

Comment: @Andrew It looks like you're providing a public key `03e8546cfe53ca9014f6a352bc2e5c1f7cec1f5b344c73d4db3ed3b8f075d5c9ef` that doesn't hash to the right value for the `OP_EQUAL` check. You need the `redeemScript` that hashes to `f45d94733d430261962932e0c847075195916a04`

Comment: What about this transaction? The public key and redeem script is the same, but it's valid tx https://tchain.btc.com/194fe9b2e266b47f51410ceb58f0765551f75bd018e7bfc3439efee14a344777

Comment: That is a witness transaction, and the `redeemScript`is provided in the `scriptSig`: `0014e17bbad678e82f8188099a351170c3e0efd4011b`

Comment: Can you spend this tx https://tchain.btc.com/46894d9dd5e20147826523b1a3ac8e8c5c64603338430d04bd6f5846af2bb9b4  ? Here is a private key: cUB1iazKDHngknjpTHUfKtH9zNRvHn1aBMPJbK2s913zUegjkeNn

Comment: @Andrew see my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85770/discussion-between-andrew-and-jbaczuk).

Comment: Oh my God! I'm so sorry, but I'm not a programmer. I have no idea how to insert redeemscript into transaction and/or how to calculate it. Is there a easy way to just spend this inputs using bitcoin-cli with the folowing private key ?